# Traces and determinant identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace

$A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with $\det(A)=0$ and tr(A) not equal to -1.

How to prove that:

$\displaystyle (I+A)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{1+\operatorname{tr}(A)}A$.

Comment: I suppose one uses the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: I tried, but did not come up with anything for now, unfortunately..

Comment: Take A to be all 1's. det(A) = 0. So tr(A) = 2. So if you try, the above equation does not equate. I think there is some error in your question

Comment: Sagar, indeed I am sorry, there should be plus, not minus in the brackets on the left-hand side.

Comment: You must also assume $\text{tr}A \neq -1$

Comment: Alex, thank you, I will make an edit

Comment: @Anton The trace *can* be zero, it cannot be $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with $\text{det}A=0$, then $A$ has one eigenvalue which is zero and another eigenvalue which is real, let's call is $\lambda$. Then $\text{tr}A = 0+\lambda = \lambda$ and the characteristic polynomial is $$c_A(x)=x(x-\lambda)=x^2-\lambda x$$ so by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem: $$A^2=\lambda A.$$
By definition of the inverse, $(I+A)^{-1}(I+A)=I$, and 
$$\left( I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda }A \right)(I+A)=I^2-\frac{1}{1+\lambda }A+A-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}A^2$$ Then plugging in $A^2=\lambda A $, the expression above becomes $$I+ \left(1-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} \right)A=I+\left(1-1 \right)A=I$$ therefore $(I+A)^{-1}=\left(I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}A \right)$ provided that $\lambda \neq -1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is a rank-1 matrix. 

The defining property of a rank-1 matrix is
$$A^2={\rm tr}(A)\,A = t A$$
The related matrix $P=\frac{A}{t}$ is idempotent, i.e. $P^2=P$.

The eigenvalues of an idempotent matrix are either $0$ or $1$.

Using Cayley-Hamilton, we can write any function of a 2x2 matrix as a quadratic polynomial
$$f(X) = \alpha_2X^2 + \alpha_1X + \alpha_0I$$
In the case of an idempotent matrix, this reduces to a linear polynomial
$$f(P) = \alpha_1P + \alpha_0I$$
whose $\alpha$-coefficients can be determined by substituting the eigenvalues into the scalar version of the polynomial. This is known as Hermite-Sylvester interpolation.

Using the function  $f(\lambda) = (t\lambda+1)^{-1}$ and the eigenvalues $\lambda=\{0,1\}$ leads to
$$\eqalign{
 f(0) &= 1 = \alpha_0 \cr
 f(1) &= \frac{1}{t+1} = \alpha_1 + \alpha_0 \cr
}$$
yielding the coefficients 
$$\eqalign{\alpha_0&=1 ,\,\,\, \alpha_1&=-\frac{t}{t+1}}$$
So the matrix function is
$$\eqalign{
 (tP+I)^{-1} &= I - \frac{tP}{t+1} \cr 
}$$
or in terms of the original matrix
$$\eqalign{
  (A+I)^{-1} &= I - \frac{A}{t+1} \cr\cr
}$$
This may seem like a lot of trouble, but you can calculate ***any*** function of $A$ the same way.

For example, let 
$$f(\lambda)=\sin(t\lambda)$$
then
$$\eqalign{
 f(0) &= \sin(0) = \alpha_0 \cr
 f(1) &= \sin(t) = \alpha_1 + \alpha_0 \cr
 &\implies \alpha_0=0 ,\,\,\, \alpha_1=\sin(t) \cr
}$$
and
$$\eqalign{
 \sin(tP) &= \alpha_1P + \alpha_0I = \sin(t) P \cr
 \sin(A) &= \frac{\sin(t)}{t} A \cr
}$$

Comment: This was very informative solution for me, thank you very much